# CDF or transformation method

Tags: statistics

given $ f_(xy)(x,y)=\frac{2}{x^2y^2}$ with $x\in[1,\infty)$ and $ 1\leq y \leq x$ what is the pdf and cdf of $w = \frac{Y}{X}$

now the book tries and handles this via the so called CDF method, using

\begin{align}
  F_W(w) &= P(W\leq w)
\\ &= P(Y\leq wx)
\end{align}
and then derives the answer from that. But I want to know if the transformation using the jacobian also works. My work shows that the answer (for the cdf) is $\frac{1}{w^2}$
Which does not correspond to the books $1$.

My work:

using $ Y=VW$ and $X=V$ the jacobian is $V$ ($W*0 - 1*V$)

\begin{align}
f_{v,w}(v,w) &= \frac{2}{v^3w^2}
\\ \int_{\frac{1}{w}}^\infty f_{v,w}(v,w) dv &= \frac{2}{w^2} \int_{\frac{1}{w}}^\infty v^{-3}
\\ &=\frac{1}{w^2} \text{for } 0 \leq w \leq 1
\end{align}

Which is no where near the $1$ (uniform) that the book tells me, is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Please: Don't write things like $F_x(x)$ if you mean $F_X(x)$.  The only reason to have two iterations of one letter of the alphabet is that capital $X$ and lower-case $x$ represent two different things.  Think of the expression $F_X(x)=\Pr(X\le x)$.  If $X$ and $x$ were the same thing, then $\Pr(X\le x)$ would be incomprehensible.  But $F_X(3)=\Pr(X\le 3)$ means something.  It is the value of $\Pr(X\le x)$ when (lower-case) $x=3$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach in terms of the Jacobian is correct.

However, there is an error in the evaluation of the definite integral, to find the marginal density of $w$ by integrating the joint density of $w$ and $v$ with respect to $v$.

$$\begin{align}
f_{V,W}(v,w) &= \frac{2}{v^3w^2}
\\ \int_{\frac{1}{w}}^\infty f_{V,W}(v,w) dv &= \frac{2}{w^2} \int_{\frac{1}{w}}^\infty v^{-3}dv
\\ &=\color{blue}{\frac{2}{w^2}\left[-\frac{v^{-2}}{2}\right]_{\frac{1}{w}}^\infty}\\&=\color{blue}{\frac{2}{w^2}\frac{w^2}{2}}\\&=\color{blue}{1} \text{ for } 0 \leq w \leq 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you explain to me how the ranges of w and v get transformed from x and y?  There may be some confusion?

Comment: from the ranges of x  and y we can see that $w \leq 1$, which gives us the corresponding limits for v,

$ 1\leq wv leq\v$ becomes $\frac{1}{v} \leq w \leq 1 $ do all sides to the power of -1 you get
$v \geq \frac{1}{v} \geq q$, and we know the upper bound of v is $\infty$ so we can say $\frac{1}{w} \leq v \leq \infty$

Comment: @Alijah : The comment I made under the question applies to your answer as well.  Your notation is wrong.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: I have just edited my answer and corrected the notation for the probability density functions. Thank you for your valid criticism.

Comment: @WiseStrawberry, I did not understand your range transformation. I think the original ranges ought to be $ y - [1,\infty]$ and $1\leq y \leq x$.  If it were that way, then $1\leq vw \leq \infty$ and $\frac{1}{w} \leq v \leq \infty$ and $\frac{1}{v} \leq w \leq \ 1$ will lead to $0\leq w \leq 1$.